# Stopping user from hitting 'back' after they have signed out of the app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, back

Once a user signs out (from the preferences), the handler signs the user out and them takes them to the initial launch page.

The only problem is the user can hit the 'back' button which takes them to the other activities where they can see the info from the logged in person. What i want to do is make it work like someone has just opened the app for the first time when they have signed out.

I've tried to send the intent of starting the activity with 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP' and 'SINGLE_TOP' flags but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: Why not check the current logged in status on all your other activities and if the user is not logged in, then direct them to the initial launch/login page? Even if they navigate there with the back button or any other way, they will be taken to the correct page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) option.

EDIT: just noticed that this is only in API 11. You'll probably need to do something like registering a BroadcastReceiver in all your Activities, then on the logout screen send an Intent that the BroadcastReceiver will catch. The Activity can then cleanly exit.

Comment: I think the best way to implement the BroadcastReceiver from what i can tell.. Now i have to find a quick tutorial on how to implement it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do, the first of which you've tried but isn't working for some reason.

One is to clear the back button stack when you launch your activity like this: `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` though I'm not sure why that's not working for you.

The other thing you can do is override the back button handling in your login activity so that it doesn't do anything. Here is example code to accomplish that:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Yes not sure what the set flags weren't working.. For the onBackPressed, the problem is that sometimes when they are settings screen, they will not be signing out, then we need to allow them to hit back... Is there a way I can just default 'onBackPressed' if user is not signed out?

Comment: Do an if/else to check if the user is logged in (I'm assuming you have a variable or method to check if they are logged in or not?). If they are logged in, call super.onBackPressed() so that the back button functions normally. If they are logged out, just return so that it does nothing.